# Trying Tesseract on Windows CMD

Tags: python, tesseract, pytesser

I'm having trouble using Tesseract-OCR with the pytesseract Python wrapper.
I figured that the problem might come from Tesseract itself, not from the wrapper.
So I tried Tesseract in CMD :

```
C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop>tesseract.exe 'blabla.jpg' 'out.txt'
```

And it returned the following lines :

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.01 with Leptonica
Error in fopenReadStream: file not found
Error in findFileFormat: image file not found
Error during processing.
```

I've done the following to install Tesseract :

- Installing from there : https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
- Adding the path of tesseract.exe to the PATH environment variable

And by the way, the problem I'm having where running my Python code :

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('blabla.jpg')
print(text)
```

is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-01e77f902509>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('D:/anaconda/projects/OCR/ocr.py', wdir='D:/anaconda/projects/OCR')

  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/anaconda/projects/OCR/ocr.py", line 48, in <module>
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(a)

  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
config=config)

  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

  File "D:\anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "D:\anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
startupinfo)

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access refused
```

Running the code as Administrator doesn't solve the problem

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Please read this ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to verify `tesseract` works or not from `Windows command prompt`, use `" "` instead of `' '` if the image and/or output file name consists of `space`. Otherwise quote symbol is not needed.

```
C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop>tesseract.exe blabla.jpg out.txt
```

Secondly, use full file path to specifc the image file. Such as,

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/path/to/tesseract.exe'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('D:/path/to/blabla.jpg'))
```

Note that forward slash `/` is used to specific any file path instead of backslash `\` , or you use double backslash `\\`, e.g. `'D:\\path\\to\\blabla.jpg'`.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your response !
It solved my first problem. However, my python code still doesn't work even with the full image path. I still get the "Access Refused"

Comment: Would you try to add `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=` to specific the `tesseract.exe` file path? Check the updated answer for sample command.